# How do I detect an empty <para> with a BREX data module

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to make sure that there are no instances of an empty `<para>` with my BREX data module using XPath 1. `//para[not(text()]` works OK unless I have all the text wrapped in `<emphasis>`, which shows as an error. How can I add wrapped text?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post your code, an example imput and the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `node()` instead of `text()` since the former covers both text nodes and element nodes as you needed :

```
//para[not(node())]
```